# Correct way of getting the current page uri

Tags: home-url

Can someone please tell me how to get the correct url of the page the user is on?  I need to grab the url and construct a new link.  Here is the issue that I am having.  For example, let's say I am on http://localhost/myplugin/samplepage/?some_var=1&some_var=2

```
home_url() is http://localhost/myplugin
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI] is /myplugin/samplepage/?some_var=1&some_var=2
```

As you can see, if I do this

```
$url = home_url() . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI];
```

The outcome will be

```
http://localhost/myplugin/myplugin/samplepage/?some_var=1&some_var=2
```

Notice the 'myplugin' in the url twice, which doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in `redirect_canonical()` uses the following:

```
$requested_url  = is_ssl() ? 'https://' : 'http://';                                                                                                                                           
$requested_url .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];                                                                                                                                                       
$requested_url .= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```